# FreeNAS installation takes up the whole disk space

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I'm very new to FreeBSD and I just installed the FreeNAS OS on a 1TB hard drive. After installing the OS, the remaining space on that specific disk seems not to available to be utilized as additional storage.

Is there a way to reclaim that space?

Comment: You mean inside the FreeNAS OS you don't see any available space? Or looking at the drive in a different instal you don't see any available space?

Comment: I have 3 disk, with one containing the OS. Two disk are available to be used as additional storage. The disk containing the OS has 1TB of space and the remaining space is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to install FreeNAS to a thumbstick / flash drive (at least 8GB) as FreeNAS cannot be partitioned with anything else once the drive is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redo it or can try ZFS:
You can create multiple Volumes from your physical disk set (equivalent to partitions of the set, not each disk)
You can create multiple Datasets in a volume (each can have a max size and various other attributes).
and yes its recommended to install FreeNAS to Flashdrive..